# How to capture the focus of a TextBox inside a ListView grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This code generates a Listview with a grid, of multiple name and emails inside TextBox control. I would like to know how can I capture the focus event on one of the TextBox of a row to have the entire ListView row to be selected.

```
<ListView Name="lstRecipients" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Recipients}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="tbNameTemplate">
            <TextBox Name="tbName" Text="{Binding Path=Username, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="tbEmailTemplate">
            <TextBox Name="tbEmail" Text="{Binding Path=Email, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="gvRecipients">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource tbNameTemplate}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Email" CellTemplate="{StaticResource tbEmailTemplate}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a handler to the [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx) event on the TextBox that sets the selected item on the ListView.  You can use [ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346420.aspx) to get the ListViewItem and [ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.itemfromcontainer.aspx) to get the bound data object.  In XAML:

```
<TextBox GotFocus="tbName_GotFocus" Name="tbName" Text="{Binding Path=Username, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

In code-behind:

```
private void tbName_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var container = lstRecipients.ContainerFromElement((DependencyObject)sender);
    if (container != null)
    {
        lstRecipients.SelectedItem = lstRecipients.ItemContainerGenerator
            .ItemFromContainer(container);
    }
}
```

You could also set the handler on the ListView, since GotFocus is a routed event.  You could use this to create a handler that could be shared between ListViews.  In XAML:

```
<ListView GotFocus="lstRecipients_GotFocus" Name="lstRecipients" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Recipients}">
```

In code-behind:

```
private void lstRecipients_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selector = sender as Selector;
    if (selector != null)
    {
        var container = selector.ContainerFromElement
            ((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
        if (container != null)
        {
            selector.SelectedItem = selector.ItemContainerGenerator
                .ItemFromContainer(container);
        }
    }
}
```

(If you don't want the TextBox to be editable at all, you could also just set `Focusable="False"` or use a TextBlock instead of a TextBox and focus would go to the ListView and select the row when the cell was clicked.)